# No lib directory after install Neo4j communitiy edition

Tags: neo4j

i have installed Neo4j community edition. The Neo4j documentation said, that all jar files exist in the lib folder. The problem is that no lib folder exist. Is it possible to download the jar from another source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What OS did you install under? Do you have a lib directory within the main Neo4j directory? Under my dev sandbox on Windows I have 20 jars in a standard install in the lib directory.

If you are using Windows, there is the installer-based distribution and the zipped no-installer version. I like the no-installer version which is easier to set up as a Windows service which can be more easily controlled/communicated with via command-line etc.

Comment: Not sure why, but the gzip version contains way more folders (including the lib) than the .exe installer. Why? Anyways it works now. Thanks